# How to authenticate a user consuming a remote WEB API trough ASP.NET MVC 5 Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I have access to a Web API which for a username and password returns a token that is valid for a certain period of time.

I could save the token in a session or in a cookie and continue to use it to get data but is there a way to connect it to Identity so I can use some built in stuff, maybe define some ClameTypes based on token, role and some other info. Does it make any sense?

If its a valid approach, is there a tutorial on how can it be done or at least some reference points? I made some MVC5-Identity apps but did not go beyond default stuff.

Comment: AspNet Identity recommended resources: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/getting-started/aspnet-identity-recommended-resources